# How to install graphite and all its prerequisites as a user without root permissions?

Tags: graphite

We are trying to install Graphite to capture neo4j database metrics. The installation will be done under the neo4j user which does not have root permissions. On the web there are multiple pages which detail this procedure but most of them fail at one stage or another. Is there a way to install all components of graphite and its pre-requisites using a non root user?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root, then you are most likely not supposed to install applications on that server and should ask you system administrator to install it for you.

That said. On which pre-requisite does it fail? You can install all Python parts in virtualenv. For cairo and other system requirements it's a bit harder but still doable. You'll also have some issues getting it started automatically after reboot.

I'm actually working on making installation easier and updating the documentation. I could use some feedback.

https://github.com/piotr1212/graphite-web/blob/setuptools/docs/install.rst#using-virtualenv  <- work in progress, you will have to follow virtualenv -> install from source, but then replace "graphite-project" with "piotr1212" in the github url's and `git checkout setuptools` in every directory before runnin `pip install .`